# Why doesn't pandas groupby.diff use the grouping keys as index?

Tags: pandas, group-by

pandas `groupby().diff()` operation does not comply with the default as `index=True` parameter and does not use the keys in `groupby` as indexes.

Unlike other aggregate functions such as `groupby().sum()` or `groupby().mean()`. I want to know the reason.

Comment: `diff` is not aggregate function

Answer (score 4):

[`groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) is a **transformation** function (not an aggregation), thus it leaves the original shape and index unchanged. It's essentially the same as `df.groupby('group').transform(lambda g: g.diff())`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': list('AAABBB'), 'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

## aggregation
df.groupby('group').sum()
#        value
# group       
# A          6
# B         15

## transformation
df.groupby('group').diff()
# or
df.groupby('group').transform(lambda g: g.diff())
#    value
# 0    NaN
# 1    1.0
# 2    1.0
# 3    NaN
# 4    1.0
# 5    1.0
```

It behaves like other transformation functions:

```
df.groupby('group').shift()
#    value
# 0    NaN
# 1    1.0
# 2    2.0
# 3    NaN
# 4    4.0
# 5    5.0
```

Another example that clearly demonstrates this would be to compare the behavior in [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) that expects a single values as output:

```
df.groupby('group').agg({'value': lambda g: g.sum()})
#        value
# group       
# A          6
# B         15

df.groupby('group').agg({'value': lambda g: g.diff()})
# ValueError: Must produce aggregated value
```